# jQuery fadeOut() not working in PHP echo

Tags: php, jquery, fadeout

I have been trying, searching, trying, researching all night to see how I can get a page to fade out after a successful PHP login and then after having faded out successfully redirect to a protected page.

Here is what I have at the moment, although it is one of the most recent of the many alterations I have been attempting:

the link:
ournewlife.com/002/login.php

and the code:

```
<?php

session_start();

if ($_GET['login']) {
     // Only load the code below if the GET
     // variable 'login' is set. You will
     // set this when you submit the form

if (in_array($_POST['entryphrase'], array('enter', 'goin', 'entrezvous', 'opensesame'))) {
         // Load code below if both username
         // and password submitted are correct

         $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
          // Set session variable

          echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
          echo "$('#ournewform').fadeOut(2222);";  
          echo "</script>";

//        header("Location: protected.php");
         exit;
         // Redirect to a protected page

     } else echo "";
     // Otherwise, echo the error message

}

?>

<form action="?login=1" method="post" id="ournewform">
    <input type="text" id="ournewlogin" name="entryphrase" class="fontface" />
</form>
```

I have also tried loading the transition after the enter key was hit from a seperate .js file, but then the PHP would not update the session and when it redirected the login would not yet be verified and would spit my back out onto the login page.

Is there anything I'm missing here?  I simply would like to fade the page out after an effective login and then successfully be brought to the protected page.

I commented out the redirect line at the moment so that I could work on the jQuery.

Comment: The js code echoed out will never get executed; It is because you are echoing out the script data and then trying to redirecct. Alos it will give an warning called "Warning: Cannot modify header information – headers already sent"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked elsewhere for the answer to this question and found very little help.  I did, however, find a login script here:

http://codecanyon.net/item/simple-secure-login-v3/2748367?sso?WT.ac=search_item&WT.seg_1=search_item&WT.z_author=phpcodemonkey

I am still having difficulty fading out, but it appears that this form uses ajax, etc, so it is likely to be of more use.  I am attempting to gather a solution up on another thread here:

[fadeOut after ajax login submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790172/fadeout-after-ajax-login-submission)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the jquery plugin and the doc ready handler:

```
      echo "<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js'></script>";
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
      echo "$(function(){";
      echo "$('#ournewform').fadeOut(2222);";  
      echo "});";
      echo "</script>";
```

Comment: After exiting just after the line that echoes out the above code, how will the code ever get to the line where the form is actually defined ?? Jquery will never find the element called "ournewform" and thus will do nothing!

Comment: Why using echo() if it's not necessary?

Comment: This method did not work.  Thank you for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Your page don't get the echoed scripts.

Comment: Sorry, Jai, I don't know what happened there.  I did try it, however, and it did not work in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ournewform').fadeOut(2222);
    window.location ='newpage.html';
});
```

In your php script you may assign this to some variable like

```
<?php
$script = "$(document).ready(function() {
               $('#ournewform').fadeOut(2222);
               window.location ='newpage.html';
           });";
```

Then in your `<body>` tag, preferably at the bottom of page, before closing the tag, you can print the variable inside `<script>` tag, like:

```
<?php if(isset($script):?>
<script type='text/javascript'><?php print $script;?></script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Put the javascript at the bottom of page will ensure the fadeOut event triggers after the form has been loaded.

You can also use `setTimeOut` function to delay the fadeOut for few milliseconds.

Comment: Sorry, Ehs4n.  I was trying to post some code here and it didn't fly.  I adapted what you put here as follows and I get a server error: http://pastebin.com/8Bb0UWy2   you can see it at ournewlife.com/002/login.php

Comment: The `$script = ` should go inside your if statement, as the redirection will be only once the user has posted the form data and it is validated. Also comment `header('Location...)` as it is handled in the javascript code itself, see `window.location`

Comment: I'm looking into this now.  I need to wait a moment for my server.  Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: @Cheryl - Please do accept this as answer, if it solves your problem.

Comment: It does redirect, but the page does not fade.

Comment: Making a bit of headway with what you started.  Added some code to stop the default action of just going to the redirect.  ournewlife.com/005/login.php     /     http://pastebin.com/E0p1YQQS

Comment: As you can see now it blinks out, fades back in, and then fades out (?!)  It's a bit closer, but still no cigar.

Comment: Oh you want to have fade effect even on successful login. That is pretty easy. Just use the setTimeout() function. Putting a new revision to your pastebin for the same. It is working as per your need now. http://pastebin.com/L1GdFhQH

Comment: This did not work.  This code in particular also disrupts the fadein of the page and still does not work after it is faded out.

Comment: What is wrong with the current code? Also for document fading, you can change the selector to `$(document).fad....`

Comment: I have put the code here so you can see it: ournewlife.com/006/login.php.  As you can see when you enter the correct code "goin", it then blinks out, fades back in, does not fade out, and then redirects.  This is almost the opposite of what I am trying to acheive.  What I am looking for is when someone enters the correct code "goin" the page simply fades out and then redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate the Javascript code from PHP. It would be more elegant if you test first if the condition has been met and then inject the javascript code:

```
<?php

session_start();

if ($_GET['login']) {
     // Only load the code below if the GET
     // variable 'login' is set. You will
     // set this when you submit the form

if (in_array($_POST['entryphrase'], array('enter', 'goin', 'entrezvous', 'opensesame'))) {
         // Load code below if both username
         // and password submitted are correct

         $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
          // Set session variable
?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
      $('#ournewform').fadeOut(2222);      
</script>

<?php }
else echo "";
     // Otherwise, echo the error message
?>
```

And do not forget to include the Jquery library in the header section.

Comment: This solution looks nice, but when I tried it I got a server error:https://www.ournewlife.com/003/login.php

Comment: That doesn't help me. Can you copy what kind of error did you got?

Comment: Sorry esmimov, that's the only error I'm getting.  Perhaps you would have some insight above...?  The page is now semi operational: ournewlife.com/005/login.php - but if you login with "enter" you'll see that it blinks out, then fades out and fades in (?!) ... the code is here, this is the best working solution so far so if you have any insights on it that would be great:  pastebin.com/E0p1YQQS

Comment: @Cheryl I suppose it's working as expected. I don't get internal server error anymore, so if it's solve your problem please accept my answer.

Comment: As I've said, the page still isn't operating according to how it's intended to operate.  If you follow the link you will see that it is not working correctly.

Comment: In pastebin code the header location is commented out. That should be the root of the problem.

Comment: After putting the location line back in this solutions still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do to achieve that effect is: Use an ajax function and log the user in and depending on the response, you can choose to either fade out the login box or show the error.

Comment: Jaspal, I missed your comment when it was first placed.  Do you have any suggestions of resources that give a step-by-step guide to accomplish this?  I haven't found any.  If you have any search terms that also may help, as I'm not sure I'm hitting it on the nose there.  Thanks!