# fadeOut after ajax login submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, authentication

I currently have a login page that fades in very nicely, it can be seen here:
ournewlife.com/001/login.php

After a user successful logs in I would like it to fade out for a similar amount of time before redirecting.  I passed a value (7777) to load.fadeOut in the following code:

```
$('#login').on('click', function(e) {
    // Some variables
    var username = $('input[name=username]').val(),
            password = $('input[name=password]').val(),
            csrf = $('input[name=csrf_field]').val(),
            load = $('.form_loader');
    feedback.slideToggle();
    load.fadeIn();
    // Check to see if any empty values..
    // I mean c'mon.. Why disturb PHP?
    if ( username === "" || password === "" || csrf === "" ) {
        feedback.removeClass().addClass('alert error').text('Please enter your username and or password!').slideToggle();
        load.fadeOut();
        return false;
    }
    // Post the data and validate it.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'process.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            username: username,
            password: password,
            csrf_field: csrf,
            task: "login"
        }, success: function(data) {
            load.fadeOut(7777);
            feedback.removeClass().addClass( (data.error === false) ? 'alert success' : 'alert error' ).html(data.message).fadeIn();
            if (data.error === false) {
                location.href = data.redirect;
            }
        }, error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            feedback.removeClass().addClass('error').text('Something went wrong. Please check the console for more information.').fadeIn();
            load.fadeOut();
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
            // console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Which is part of the larger code here:

```
 jQuery.support.placeholder = (function(){
 var i = document.createElement('input');
 return 'placeholder' in i;
 })();

$(document).ready( function() {

$("body").css("display", "none");
$("body").fadeIn(6666);

// Does it support placeholders?
if ( $.support.placeholder ) {
    // Let the users know what to enter.
    $('.input-block > label').hide();
}

// Global Variables
feedback = $('#feedback');

// Hide the JS message
$('.no-js').hide();

/**
 * Called when the user forgets their password.
 */
$('#forgot_password').on('click', function() {
    // Some variables.
    var email = $('input[name=email]').val();
    feedback.fadeOut();
    if ( email === "" ) {
        feedback.removeClass().addClass('alert error').text('Please fill out all required fields!').slideToggle();
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            email: email,
            task: 'forgot_password'
        }, success: function(data) {
            feedback.removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'alert error' : 'alert success').text(data.message).slideToggle();
        }
    });
    return false;
});

$('#save_settings').on('click', function() {
    feedback.fadeOut();
    var allow_reg = parseInt($('#registration').val()),
            location = $('#location').val();
    $.post('process.php', {
        allow_reg: allow_reg,
        location: location,
        task: 'save_settings'
    }, function( data ) {
        if ( data.error === false ) {
            // We have no errors.
            feedback.removeClass().addClass('alert success').text(data.message).slideToggle();
        }
    }, 'json');
    return false;
});

/**
 * Called when the user registers a new account.
 */
$('#register').on('click', function() {
    // Some variables.
    var username = $('input[name=username]').val(),
            password = $('input[name=password]').val(),
            email = $('input[name=email]').val(),
            captcha = $('input[name=captcha]').val();
            feedback.fadeOut();
    // Some validation.
    if ( username === "" || password === "" || email === "" || captcha === "") {
        feedback.removeClass().addClass('alert error').text('Please fill out all required fields!').slideToggle();
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            username: username,
            password: password,
            email: email,
            captcha: captcha,
            task: 'new_user'
        }, success: function(data) {
            feedback.removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'alert error' : 'alert success').text(data.message).slideToggle();
        }
    });
    return false;
});

/**
 * When the user clicks on the login button.
 */
$('#login').on('click', function(e) {
    // Some variables
    var username = $('input[name=username]').val(),
            password = $('input[name=password]').val(),
            csrf = $('input[name=csrf_field]').val(),
            load = $('.form_loader');
    feedback.slideToggle();
    load.fadeIn();
    // Check to see if any empty values..
    // I mean c'mon.. Why disturb PHP?
    if ( username === "" || password === "" || csrf === "" ) {
        feedback.removeClass().addClass('alert error').text('Please enter your username and or password!').slideToggle();
        load.fadeOut();
        return false;
    }
    // Post the data and validate it.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'process.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            username: username,
            password: password,
            csrf_field: csrf,
            task: "login"
        }, success: function(data) {
            load.fadeOut(7777);
            feedback.removeClass().addClass( (data.error === false) ? 'alert success' : 'alert error' ).html(data.message).fadeIn();
            if (data.error === false) {
                location.href = data.redirect;
            }
        }, error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            feedback.removeClass().addClass('error').text('Something went wrong. Please check the console for more information.').fadeIn();
            load.fadeOut();
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
            // console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
});

$('#forgot-password').on('click', function() {
    // Some variables.
    var forgotEmail = $('input#forgot-email').val(),
            feedback = $('#feedback'),
            load = $('#loading');

    feedback.fadeOut();
    load.fadeIn();
    if (forgotEmail === "") {
        load.fadeOut();
        feedback.removeClass().addClass('error').text('Please enter your email so that I can work with it!').fadeIn();
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'process.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            forgotEmail: forgotEmail
        }, success: function(data) {
            load.fadeOut();
            feedback.removeClass().addClass( (data.error === false) ? 'success' : 'error' ).text(data.message).fadeIn();
        }, error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            feedback.removeClass().addClass('error').text('Something went wrong. Please check the console for more information.').fadeIn();
            load.fadeOut();
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;
});

/** TODO: Do this **/
$('#renew-password').on('click', function() {
    var passwordOne = $('input#re-password').val(),
            passwordTwo = $('input#re-password-2').val(),
            emailReset = $('input#email-reset').val(),
            resetCode = $('input#reset-code').val(),
            feedback = $('#feedback'),
            load = $('#loading');

    feedback.fadeOut();
    load.fadeIn();

    if ( (passwordOne === "") || (passwordTwo === "") || (emailReset === "") || resetCode === "") {
        load.fadeOut();
        feedback.removeClass().addClass('error').text('Please enter your new password, two times!').fadeIn();
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'process.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            passwordOne: passwordOne,
            passwordTwo: passwordTwo,
            emailReset: emailReset,
            resetCode: resetCode
        }, success: function(data) {
            load.fadeOut();
            feedback.removeClass().addClass( (data.error === false) ? 'success' : 'error' ).text(data.message).fadeIn();
        }, error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            feedback.removeClass().addClass('error').text('Something went wrong. Please check the console for more information.').fadeIn();
            load.fadeOut();
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });

    return false;
});

 });
```

I've searched elsewhere and attempted other solutions and they have not worked.  I reverted back to this one because it seemed the simplest and most straight forward.  If anyone has any idea on how to accomplish this that would be wonderful!

Comment: Use an onsuccess $.ajax callback:

Comment: I don't quite understand.  Isn't the success: function(data) already handling the fact that the submission is sucessful?

Comment: BTW: the login and pass are admin/password.

Comment: I recommand to disable the display by css, because when loading the page, you get a flash of the body, then display none and fadein again..

Answer (score 0):

use the fadeOut callback :

```
feedback.removeClass().addClass( (data.error === false) ? 'alert success' : 'alert error' ).html(data.message).fadeIn();
load.fadeOut(7777, function() {
       if (data.error === false) {
            location.href = data.redirect;
        }
});
```

Comment: success: function(data) {

  if(data.error) load.fadeOut(7, function() { feedback.removeClass().addClass('alert error').html(data.message).fadeIn(); });
  else $("body").fadeOut(4444, function() { 
  //feedback.removeClass().addClass('alert success').html(data.message).fadeIn(); 
  setTimeout(new Function("location.href = '" + data.redirect+ "';"));
   });

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data) {
  if(data.error){
    feedback.removeClass().addClass('alert error').html(data.message);
  } else {
    load.fadeOut(7777, function(){
      window.location.href = data.redirect;
    }
  }
}
```

That's how I'd do it. If the login is incorrect, you don't really want to be waiting around for the fadeOut to do it's thing before trying again.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the tips.  This code worked:

```
 success: function(data) { 
      if(data.error) load.fadeOut(7, function() { 
        feedback.removeClass().addClass('alert error').html(data.message).fadeIn();
        }); 
      else $("body").fadeOut(4444, function() { 
        //feedback.removeClass().addClass('alert success').html(data.message).fadeIn(); 
        setTimeout(new Function("location.href = '" + data.redirect+ "';")); 
 });
```